# file beats not harvesting live logs

Tags: logstash, filebeat

i have file beats installed on a client machine. it is suppose to run as a service and send logs  to logstash , its not happening. hence i tried to do some changes in the yml of file beats ran manually `./filebeat  -e -c filebeat.yml -d "publish"` it still did not send the logs to logstash , but did genrate some own logs for file beats. 
i  was havin doubt whether logstash its nor running , did  verify it form the services , it was running . but still manually tried to run it. am posting here the config file of that also.

[log of file beat](https://anotepad.com/notes/x97riiq)

[file beat yml](https://anotepad.com/notes/y25b55w)

[log stash log](https://jpst.it/1PgSg)

[logstash configration](https://anotepad.com/notes/syi5dxm)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some errors in your logstash logs, always a good idea to search logs for any error messages.

```
[2019-08-25T11:54:08,690][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, => at line 81, column 7 (byte 1562) after input {\r\n \tbeats {\r\n \t\tport => \"5044\"\r\n \t\t \r\n\t }\r\n#
```

Please try removing the quotations around your port number in the beats input in your logstash.conf

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html